# WordPress Pagination Won't Switch Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, pagination

I have been searching for a solution to this issue for over a week and I haven't been able to find anybody else with the same trouble.

I am working on a custom WP theme that somebody else built. There is a single-page template that I need to implement paging on for one of the secondary loops. I have been attempting to use the built-in `paginate_links()` function, as well as other methods. The pagination links show up, but when I click on a pagination link it doesn't go to that page in the pagination. Instead the original page is reloaded (i.e. instead of going to thewebsite.com/my-page/page/2/, it reloads thewebsite.com/my-page/).

The previous dev used this filter in functions.php to load the correct template:

```
add_filter('single_template', create_function('$t', 'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) { if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php"; } return $t;' ));
```

And here is my template file:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Project Template
*/
get_header('news'); ?>

<article role="main" class="projectpage">
<div class="container">
  <section class="pagecontent">


      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
      <section class="overview">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <div>
              <?php the_content(); ?>
          </div>
          <div>
              <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pagelink', true)): ?>
                  <a href ="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pagelink', true); ?>" class="ctabutton2">  Read the Overview </a>
              <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

</div><!--end row-->
   </section><!--end overview-->
   <?php endwhile ?>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
   <? endif ?>


   <section class="related">
       <div>
           <h1> Related Resources </h1>
           <h2> Explore our library of articles and resources </h2>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 relatedlinks">
               <section class="projectcategories">
                   <h3> Categories </h3>
                   <ul>
                       <?php wp_list_categories( array(
                           'orderby'            => 'id',
                           'show_count'         => true,
                           'use_desc_for_title' => false,
                           'child_of'           => 93,
                           'title_li' => ' '
                       ) ); ?>
                   </ul>
               </section>

               <section class="project-search" role="search">

                   <form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                       <input type="hidden" name="cat" id="cat" value="93" />
                       <input type="text" size="16" name="s" placeholder="search keywords" class="search-box" />
                       <input type="submit" value="Go" class="go"/>
                   </form>

               </section>

               <section class="otherprojects">
                   <h3> Other Projects </h3>

                   <?php
                   $args = array(
                       'category__in' => 91,
                       'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
                   );
                   // the query
                   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                   $temp_query = $wp_query;
                   $wp_query = NULL;
                   $wp_query = $query;

                   // The Loop
                   if ( $query->have_posts() ) :  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                   <? endwhile ;
                       /* Restore original Post Data */
                       wp_reset_postdata();
                   endif;


                   $wp_query = NULL;
                   $wp_query = $temp_query;
                   ?>
               </section>
           </div><!--end col 1-->

          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <section class="articles">

              <?php
//  THIS IS THE SECTION WHERE I NEED THE PAGINATION
              $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

              $args = [
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
                'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => '93',
                ],
              ],
            ];

            $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
              $temp_query = $wp_query;
              $wp_query = NULL;
              $wp_query = $custom_query;
                                if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                                    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                                        $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 divider">
                                                <p class="date"><?php the_time('M j') ?></p>
                                            </div><!--end col-->
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                                <div class="articleimg">
                                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {?>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-thumb'); ?></a>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                </div><!--end blogimg-->
                                            </div><!--end col-->
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="blogcontent">
                                                    <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                                                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"> // read more </a>
                                                </div><!--end blogcontent-->
                                            </div><!--end col-->
                                    </div><!--end row-->
            <?php }
                }

          echo paginate_links(array(
              'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
          ));


              $wp_query = NULL;
              $wp_query = $temp_query;
              wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </section><!--end articles-->
          </div><!--end col 2-->
        </div> <!--end row-->
      </section><!--end related-->


<!--   ANNOUNCEMENTS    -->
   <!--ANNOUNCEMENT SECTION -->
   <!-- dynamic content --filters posts by category and only shows 'member' posts with a limit of six posts being
   displayed-->
   <section id="announcement-front" class="clearfix">
       <div class="container">
           <div>
               <?php $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&category_name=advertisement');
               if ($query->have_posts()) :
                   while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" <?php the_content();?> </a>
                   <?php endwhile ?>
               <? endif ?>
               <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
           </div><!--end row-->
       </div><!--container-->
   </section><!--end announcement-->


  </section> <!--end page content -->
</div><!--end container-->
        </article>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I realize there is a whole galaxy of WordPress pagination tutorials and threads out there, but I haven't been able to find one yet that solves this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should mostly work. You don't need to worry about all the saving and switching of `$wp_query` though - have you tried this simpler snippet? It worked ok in my environment (though I had to modify the query args slightly to get it to return any results).

If that's not working can you post the HTML it generates?

```
        <section class="articles">
          <?php
//  THIS IS THE SECTION WHERE I NEED THE PAGINATION
          $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

          $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => '93',
            ],
          ],
        ];

        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
                                    $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="row">
                                     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 divider">
                                            <p class="date"><?php the_time('M j') ?></p>
                                        </div><!--end col-->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                            <div class="articleimg">
                                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {?>
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-thumb'); ?></a>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            </div><!--end blogimg-->
                                        </div><!--end col-->
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                            <div class="blogcontent">
                                                <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
                                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"> // read more </a>
                                            </div><!--end blogcontent-->
                                        </div><!--end col-->
                                </div><!--end row-->
        <?php }
            }

      echo paginate_links(array(
          'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages
      ));

          wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </section><!--end articles-->
      </div><!--end col 2-->
    </div> <!--end row-->
  </section><!--end related-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jo. This is actually the code I was working with originally, then read a tutorial about saving and switching `$wp_query` and tried it out. The pagination links generated appear to be right:

    `<span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://thewebsite.com/my-page/page/2/">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://thewebsite.com/my-page/page/3/">3</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://thewebsite.com/my-page/page/2/">Next »</a>`

But when I click them it just loads the original page.

Comment: Ah I see. It's not the paging links that are the problem, it's the way your page is redirected when you click on them. First try flushing your permalinks (go to Settings -> Permalinks and click Save), and if that doesn't work, try this link for ideas? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-on-singlephp-causing-301-redirect/?replies=10

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jo!  That article pointed me in the right direction. I checked in dev tools and I was indeed getting a 301. I tried the code snippet from the article you pointed me to, and it didn't quite work, so I googled "fix pagination with redirect_canonical" and [this was the first article that popped up](https://wpsoul.com/pagination-fix-for-wordpress-4-4-1/). I took the function from there, threw it in to functions.php, *et voilà*! It's the same method, but, I think, not passing a custom post type into the conditional. I hope this can help someone in the future. It was a real pain. It was also a reminder of how very little I really know about WP and how much I want to learn about it! Thanks again.

Here's the code:

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','custom_disable_redirect_canonical');
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
    if (is_paged() && is_singular()) $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
```